# .net core 2 user-secrets executable missing

Tags: .net-core

I can see the framework installed from the NuGet installer. I've changed director so that when I run the "dir" command the .csproj file is returned in the list. Here's my CSPROJ file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

<PropertyGroup>
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
 </PropertyGroup>

 <ItemGroup>
  <Compile Remove="Models\ApplicationUser.cs" />
 </ItemGroup>

 <ItemGroup>
   <None Remove="Properties\PublishProfiles\bcltProdAdmin - Web Deploy.pubxml" />
    <None Remove="Properties\PublishProfiles\bcltProdAdmin-bcltBETAAdmin - Web Deploy.pubxml" />
   <None Remove="Properties\PublishProfiles\bcltSignIn-bcltDevAdmin - Web Deploy.pubxml" />
 </ItemGroup>

 <ItemGroup>
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.8" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.0.3" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" Version="2.0.2" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.4" />
   <PackageReference Include="Sendgrid" Version="9.9.0" />
   <PackageReference Update="Microsoft.NETCore.App" Version="2.0.7" />
 </ItemGroup>

 <ItemGroup>
   <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
 </ItemGroup>

 <ItemGroup>
   <Folder Include="Properties\PublishProfiles\" />
 </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

dotnet user-secrets -h
dotnet : No executable found matching command "dotnet-user-secrets"

Answer (score 2):

I goofed on the CSPROJ entry. The correct line to add was:

```
 <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" Version="2.0.2" />
```